# Javascript vertical-flipping book using "Booklet" plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, flip

I've been using this jQuery plugin successfuly for horizontal-flipping of pages:
http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/

I've even been able to leverage it for less traditional formats like tri-fold folders, etc.

But I'm stuck on how to do a vertical-flipping version for, for example, a calendar.

Does anyone know how to do this?

CSS3 rotations come to mind but I need IE7 support

Answer (score 0):

what about JQuery Flip
http://lab.smashup.it/flip/

Comment: It's encouraging visually, but doesn't scale easily for multi-page applications (like the calendar). jQuery Flip seems more for "see the other side" more than "flip through a collection of pages"

I'm trying to simulate a physical product that is center-bound (again, like a calendar)

I'm wondering if anyone has tweaked the Booklet plugin (which allows you to drop in dozens of pages easily and handles the page-turning effects automatically) to do so in vertical fashion.

Comment: You can made it scalable to multi-page. you can do it very easily. Just for a hint you can use the events associated with flip. After each flip you can load new Page to the element